# Cryptic symbols after closing </html> in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, cross-browser, magnolia

A Website running on Magnolia 4.4.9 works perfectly good in all Browsers except Chrome. In chrome, one page ends with a ton of cryptic characters. [Page](https://www.alpeninitiative.ch/mitmachen/mitglied-werden/)

[image]

When inspecting the code, I see that they're **after** the closing `</html>` statement, even in the original source code (right click -> show page source code). This problem persists on different OS' (Windows 7, Mac OS X, Ubuntu 13.04) and does not always create the same cryptic character sequence.

What could be a possible explanation for this behaviour? Could it be an encoding problem?

Answer (score 3):

http://jira.magnolia-cms.com/browse/MAGNOLIA-3821

Upgrade to 4.4.10 or 4.5.7

HTH,
Jan

Comment: Oh, I hadn't found that one, will try to upgrade ASAP. Thx.

Comment: 4.4.10 is only available as enterprise edition, right? Will it ever be published for community?

Answer (score 1):

When comparing the source in Chrome and Safari on Mountain Lion, I noticed that **`p#copyright-magnolia` has different content between browsers**:

- on Chrome, I see `... Intuitive CMS Software ...`
- On Safari, I see `... SEO-friendly CMS ...`

Is there any configuration or code that could be causing different content to be sent out to different browsers?

Also, in Chrome, the Elements view of the Developer tools puts the garbage output right after the `<!-- end wrapper -->` comment and interprets the content, in part, as matched tags. Further, there is a `div#a11y-hidden` (and other content) right after the garbage and before the closing tags. However, I don't see `div#a11y-hidden` in the ordinary source view in Chrome or Safari.

Do you see the same thing?

These seem like clues to where the trouble is coming from.

Comment: The `copyright-magnolia` stuff is not the problem, it's automatically generated by Magnolia and changes on every page load. I see the garbage stuff inbetween others when using the inspector. However, when right-clicking > "View source", the garbage is at the very end (Chrome must have moved it on page load). Thx for your effort!